# How to compress any document received as a stream content in .net core web api?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a pdf document of 25MB received as a request parameter as a FileStrem , I want to compress or reduced it's size. How can I achieve this in .net 6 ?

I tried the GzipStream to compressed it but it's not working .

Comment: Can you share your Gzip function?

Comment: @foadabdollahi  
// Using DeflateStream
using var compressStream = new MemoryStream();
using var compressor = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
file.CopyTo(compressor);
compressor.Close();
var c = compressStream.ToArray();

// Using GZipStream
Stream stream;                            
using (FileStream destinationFile = File.Create("test.pdf"))
using (GZipStream output = new(destinationFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    files.FileStream.CopyTo(output);
    stream = output.BaseStream;
}

Answer (score 0):

The GzipStream is used to compress and decompress only the files which is in GZIP format.

If you want to compress your pdf document you can use PdfSharp and DotnetZip package,which is free and open source.

example:

```
public static void CompressPdf(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath)
{
    // Load the input PDF document
    using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(inputFilePath))
    {
        var pdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(inputStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

        // Create a new, empty output PDF document
        var outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

        // Compress each page of the input document and add it to the output document
        foreach (var page in pdfDocument.Pages)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Save the page to a stream
                page.Save(stream, false);

                // Compress the stream using DotNetZip
                stream.Position = 0;
                var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
                using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.AddEntry("Page" + page.PageNumber.ToString(), stream);
                    zip.Save(compressedStream);
                }

                // Create a new PDF page from the compressed stream and add it to the output document
                compressedStream.Position = 0;
                var compressedPage = PdfReader.Open(compressedStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import).Pages[0];
                outputDocument.AddPage(compressedPage);
            }
        }

        // Save the compressed PDF document to the output file
        using (var outputStream = File.Create(outputFilePath))
        {
            outputDocument.Save(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```